# Learning 2-D Arrays in Java- School Work

Tags: java

I'm a bit confused on how to start this problem I'm doing. I am trying to have a 2-d array that eventually will compute the distances between two points. I'm confused about how to go about setting up the array. The way it works is that the user will give me the amount of points (x, y coordinates). That will be the length of both arrays (row and column). I now need to fill in the array with the user's input. Here's how I have it set up so far:

```
    int points, x , y;

    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of points: ");
    points = scan.nextInt();

    int[][] coord = new int[points][points];
    for(int i =0; i < coord.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < coord[i].length; j++){
            System.out.println("Please enter the x coordinates: ");
            x = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter the y coordinates: ");
            y = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to get the x and y coordinates separately and then fill in the array with them. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: What are x and y supposed to be representing? The way this is set up, the array will be a square, and the for loops will take you through the map, but then for each cell you're asking for 2 numbers, what are you intending to do with them? Were you meaning to ask for one piece of data at a specific point in the map?

Comment: X and Y are supposed to represent the x and y coordinates of the array. They are both going to be the same amount. I am eventually going to use the distance formula. But that's outside of the scope of what I am asking. I am simply trying to fill in my array with the user's input.

Comment: I was talking about the variables `int x` and `int y` in your code, why are you asking for 2 ints for every cell in the array? Are they supposed to represent a place in the array you want to enter data in, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already know that you are having only x and y cooridnates, I am hardcoding this number. 
Change your code like this :

```
int[][] coord = new int[points][2]; 
    for(int i =0; i < points; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the x coordinates: "); 
            x = scan.nextInt(); 
            System.out.println("Please enter the y coordinates: "); 
            y = scan.nextInt(); 
           coord[i][0]=x;
            coord[i][1]=y;
    }
```

Comment: How would this work? The number of x and y coordinates is the same, but dependent on the what the user enters. So if the user says there's 10 points. The array is new int[points][points]. No?

Comment: I think you are confused with how multi dimensional array works.This is not the combination of two indiviudal arrays. When we create array with `int[points][2]`, think it this way. At first 1D array will be created with lenght of `points`. now Each placeholder of that array will have another `array` of  lenght '2'  (for your `x` and `y`).

Comment: That makes sense, however, for some reason, the prompt for the x and y coordinates are on an infinite loop right now instead of going points indexes long.

Comment: this pics can help you understand I guess. http://xoax.net/cpp/crs/console/lessons/Lesson52/Image2.png  . By the way it works fine . You probabaly have some other loop that is running infinite. Assumming you still ask from user to get value for `points`

Comment: I understand that now. The way I have my loop set up is:

Comment: int[][] coord = new int[points][2];
  for(int i = 0; i < points; i ++){

Comment: and that is going in infinite loop?

Comment: Never mind. For some reason that infinite loop is only happening in debug mode. I must of have set up my breakpoints weird or something. Thank you. I think I'll be able to move on from here.